# Guardar DGV en base de datos

Tags: c#

lo que quiero hacer es que al darle el botón de guardar se guarden los datos ingresados de mi datagridview en mi base de datos mi base de datos se llama *kitchen* 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es mi DGV y solo quiero guardar el id y el nombre
De antemano gracias

Comment: entiendo la db que usas es sql server, no?

Comment: es mysql, encontre algunas algunas formas como aqui http://www.forosdelweb.com/f29/guardar-gridview-base-datos-874075/

Comment: Pero no me funcionan, creo que es de otra forma

Comment: edite el codigo para suar los componente de mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `ado.net` la estructura del codigo seria algo como lo siguiente

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["keyconfig"].ConnectionString; 

using (MySqlSqlConnection conn = new MySqlSqlConnection(connstring)) { 
    conn.Open(); 

    string query = "INSERT INTO kitchen (id, nombre) VALUES (?id, ?nombre)"; 
    MySqlSqlCommand cmd = new MySqlSqlCommand(query, conn); 


    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { 
        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value)); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nombre"].Value)); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```

se iteran las rows del grid y se van asando por parametro en el INSERT

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void agregarGrid()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow Tupla in dtgDistribucion.Rows)
        {
            int cont = dtgDistribucion.Rows.Count;
            odatos.nombre_empleado = Convert.ToString(Tupla.Cells["Nombre"].Value);
            odatos.puesto = Convert.ToString(Tupla.Cells["Puesto"].Value);
            odatos.area = Convert.ToString(Tupla.Cells["Area"].Value);
            odatos.actividad_realizada = Convert.ToString(Tupla.Cells["Actividad_Realiza"].Value);
            odatos.id_folio = negocio.obtenerIdProd();

            if (Servicio.InsertarPersonal(odatos) == 1)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Mensaje("Error!!! Al agregar empleado");
            }
        }

      }
```